# HTML Paragraphs Align Format Problem from database

Tags: html, asp.net

I developing a HTML report in asp.net. I am storing a Paragraph in the Database. While fetching it in the Report word break occurs. I used Word-wrap but nothing change happens. Kindly look into the Image[image]

and the coding is below

```
<table style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial sans-serif; margin-top: 20px; word-break: break-word">
            <tr style="background-color: #133B6C; padding: 5px; color: white;">
                <td style="float: left;">

                    <b>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label14" CssClass="lblDetails" runat="server" Text="Justification"></asp:Label>
                    </b>

                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="txtJuristification" runat="server"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just replace `&nbsp;` to `' '` in database. it gets solved.